# Could not find and execute start-all.sh and Stop-all.sh on Cloudera VM for Hadoop

Tags: bash, shell, hadoop, cloudera

How to `start / Stop` services from command line `CDH4 --`. I am new to Hadoop. Installed VM from Cloudera. Could not find `start-all.sh` and `stop-all.sh` . How to stop or start the task tracker or data node if I want. It is a single node cluster which I am using on Centos. I haven't dont any modifications.

More over I see there are changes in the directory structures in all flavours. I could not locate these sh files on the VM for my installation.

```
[cloudera@localhost ~]$ stop-all.sh
bash: stop-all.sh: command not found
```

Highly appreciate your support.

Comment: try ./stop-all.sh in the directory where stop-all.sh exists.

Comment: Hadoop services if not managed by cloudera manager can be located in /etc/init.d/hadoop-*. If they exist use the command `service stop hadoop-<servicename>`. Otherwise you have to connect to your cloudera manager web UI. It is usually running in port 7180. So try http://localhost:7180.

Answer (score 0):

use Sudo su hdfs to start and to stop just type exit it will stop all the services.

Comment: add the source will make better understanding